# Replace specific query string value with IIS redirect maps

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a redirect rule for a .NET Core project that would replace a query string value so to help deploy a migration on some identifiers. For example the URL:

```
http://www.somesite.com/page.html?somevar=abc&id=1234&othervar=cde
```

should redirect to

```
http://www.somesite.com/page.html?somevar=abc&id=b64540a6-b12d-443f-973f-673e4451ccbe&othervar=cde
```

On the rewrite file I've created a rewrite map as such:

```
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="newIdentifierMap">
      <add key="1234" value="b64540a6-b12d-443f-973f-673e4451ccbe" />
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

But now I'm having some trouble creating the rule to use this map. This is what I was doing...

```
<rule>
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{newIdentifierMap:REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)id=([0-9]+)(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="" RedirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Now I'm block without knowing how exactly to replace the values in the map.
Thanks for any help!

**Solution**

After checking the answer provided by @abraham-qian I was able to solve the issue by applying the following rules:

```
<rule>
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)(\bid=([0-9]+))(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}?{C:1}id={newIdentifierMap:{C:3}}{C:4}" RedirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>

<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="newIdentifierMap">
      <add key="1234" value="b64540a6-b12d-443f-973f-673e4451ccbe" />
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

This seems to be working fine with any number of variables before or after the id variable in the querystring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to match the ID segment, we could use `{Query_String}` server variable.
Please refer to below code snippets,

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="MyRules" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)(\bid=([0-9]+))(.*)" />
          </conditions>
<!--{C:3} is the value of id, it is referred by the above condition.-->
          <action type="Redirect" url="Https://vabqia969vm:448/{MyMap:{C:3}}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="MyMapName" defaultValue="">
          <add key="1234" value="HtmlPage1.html"></add>
        </rewriteMap>
      </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

However, there is an issue that we should uncheck the option `Append Query String`, or will cause an endless loop since the appended query string meets the condition. We have to match each query field one by one. Like this,

```
(somevar=.*)&(\bid=([0-9]+))&(othervar=.*)
```

We had better modify the rules according to your situation.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.